# Matlab: Fit a custom function to xy-data with given x-y errors

Tags: matlab, optimization, curve-fitting, least-squares

I have been looking for a Matlab function that can do a nonlinear total least square fit, basically fit a custom function to data which has errors in all dimensions. The easiest case being x and y data-points with different given standard deviations in x and y, for every single point. This is a very common scenario in all natural sciences and just because most people only know how to do a least square fit with errors in y does not mean it wouldn't be extremely useful. I know the problem is far more complicated than a simple y-error, this is probably why most (not even physicists like myself) learned how to properly do this with multidimensional errors.

I would expect that a software like matlab could do it but unless I'm bad at reading the otherwise mostly useful help pages I think even a 'full' Matlab license doesn't provide such fitting functionality. Other tools like Origin, Igor, Scipy use the freely available fortran package "ODRPACK95", for instance. There are few contributions about total least square or deming fits on the file exchange, but they're for linear fits only, which is of little use to me.

I'd be happy for any hint that can help me out

kind regards

Comment: First of all, i would suggest to stick into Matlab. Surely there is an algorithm over there.

Comment: Perhaps [this FEX submission](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31109-total-least-squares-method) and [this accompanying paper](http://actamont.tuke.sk/pdf/2010/n2/8petras.pdf) will help.

Comment: well... I thought there should be an algorithm implemented in Matlab for considering both x and y errors but I haven't found anything. 
I looked at what's available on the FileExchange but there are only two implementations for linear fits. I need to be able to fit nonlinear models though.

Answer (score 0):

First I should point out that I haven't practiced MATLAB much since I graduated last year (also as a Physicist). That being said, I remember using

```
    lsqcurvefit()
```

in MATLAB to perform non-linear curve fits. Now, this may, or may not work depending on what you mean by *custom function*? I'm assuming you want to fit some *known* expression similar to one of these,

```
    y = A*sin(x)+B
    y = A*e^(B*x) + C
```

It is *extremely* difficult to perform a fit without knowning the form, e.g. as above. Ultimately, all mathematical functions can be approximated by polynomials for small enough intervals. This is something you might want to consider, as MATLAB does have lots of tools for doing polynomial regression.

In the end, I would acutally reccomend you to write your own fit-function. There are tons of examples for this online. The idea is to know the true solution's form as above, and guess on the parameters, *A,B,C...*. Create an error- (or cost-) function, which produces an quantitative error (deviation) between your data and the guessed solution. The problem is then reduced to *minimizing* the error, for which MATLAB has lots of built-in functionality.

Comment: sure I know lsqcurvefit and yeah, we're in agreement here. I know how to do all that and Matlab provides plenty of curve fitting functionalities, BUT: My problem evolves around a fit of data with known errors in the y AND in the x variable.